# Java - Wait for shell to complete tar task before process ends

Tags: java, shell, tar

I'm using java's "Process" command to execute a shell script.

In this shell script, it will break down files (from a folder) into smaller Mbs.

Once the files are being broken down, I will use SMTP to mail over those files via email.

The problem is, my mailing function runs before the shell script could actually finish chopping down my files. In the end, no email was being sent out (because apparently the folder is empty).

Here are my codes:

```
try {       
     log.info("Going to run the runtime.getRuntime() to execute tar zip files");
     String tarLocation = prop.getProperty("tarzipfile.location") + prop.getProperty("tarshell.name");
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", tarLocation}); 
     p.waitFor(); //This waitfor only waits for process, but not the shell to complete
     log.info("exit: " + p.exitValue());
     p.destroy();
} catch(Exception e) {
      log.info("ERROR: Runtime error failed to tar files", e);
}

robot.process(); //Send out mail
```

My tar file

```
cd <my file dir>
tar cvzf - <my other file dir> | split --bytes=4MB - archive.tar.gz
```

What is a good way to counter this problem besides letting it 'sleep' for a few seconds?

Comment: you are confused.  The process you are starting is the shell.

Comment: The process-class provides [Process#getInputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) to get the output of the command. Reading the content of this stream will provide some valuable information. Or alternatively use a `ProcessBuilder` and [`ProcessBuilder#redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect)) to achieve the same thing in an easier way. Same should also be used for the error-stream

Comment: @MK Sorry about that. So then, why even with p.waitFor() method, it doesn't wait for the files to be completely chopped up before moving on to the robot.process() metdho?

Comment: It probably does wait, m.b. you are looking in the wrong folder or m.b. you are not looking correctly, or may be you are not sending email correctly.  You need to run this in a debugger, or add some debug logging and figure out what exactly is going on.